# Adding Complex Objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm setting up .NET Core API. My application is divided into 3 layers:

- Data Access
- Business Logic/Services
- API

I'm having troubles added related objects with the API method. Let's say I have following classes.

```
public class Part
{
    [Key]public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string ICollection<PartAttribute> PartAttributes{get; set;}
}

public class PartAttribute
{
    [Key]public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

And following methods for interaction with DB - context is EF DbContext:

```
public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
    Context.Set<T>()
        .Add(entity);
}
```

I'm having trouble adding Part that have already existing PartAttributes, if I send following JSON via API (assuming that following record in PartAttributes already exist)

```
{
        "Name":"Example1",   
        "PartAttributes":[
        {
            "attributeId":1,
            "name":"Color",
            "value":"black"
        }]
}
```

I'm getting a following exception: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PartAttributes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." - This leads me to conclusion that EF is not recognizing the existing record and tries to insert it as new one. This results in fail because of identity insert setting in SQL Server itself.

What I'd like to achieve is that the existing objects would be recognized and EF would not try to insert the existing attributes as new records in the database. What are the best practices to achieve that behaviour?

Comment: The way you modelled it, each `PartAttributes` exclusively belongs to one `Part`. A new part can only insert new `PartAttributes`, not refer to existing ones. I think you need a many-to-many association.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your primary key (which here looks to be attributeId) and load the record using the dbContext. Once loaded update the values and call `SaveChanges()` or `SaveChangesAsync()` on the context.

You can even have a method that does insert or update.

for example (SUDO CODE!):

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(PartAttribute model)
{
  var existingRecord = dbContext.Set<PartAttribute>().Find(model.attributeId);
  if(existingRecord == null)
  { // Insert (Should not include value for attributeId)
     dbContext.Add(model);
  }
  else
  { // Update
    existingRecord = model;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you still have issues

Comment: I may have skipped part of the information necessary to anwser the question. I'm using UnitOfWork pattern, so in the services layer im SavingChanges with DbContext via unit of work. In my scenario I'm adding the Part object via Post method in PartController resulting in calling `dbContext.Set<Part>.Add(part)`. In case the PartAttributes are new, the JSON structure will not contain the PartAttributeId and during insertion EF will take care of creating PartAttribute. The problem occurs when some of the PartAttributes are already existing they're not recognized, so EF is trying to add them again.